# Problema al generar excel con maatwebsite/excel desde laravel en el servidor

Tags: laravel, servidor, maatwebsite

Estoy usando el paquete maatwebsite en Laravel al hacerlo funcionar en local funciona bien pero al subirlo al hosting me marca error 500 y en el laravel.log me sale esto:

> [2023-07-01 19:03:22] production.ERROR: syntax error, unexpected identifier "Closure", expecting variable {"userId":3,"exception":"[object] (ParseError(code: 0): syntax error, unexpected identifier "Closure", expecting variable at /home/u310019388/domains/fwien.com/public_html/fwien/vendor/maennchen/zipstream-php/src/ZipStream.php:111) [stacktrace] #0

Ya limpie cache, ya recargue las clases, ya le di todos los permisos a las carpetas en el servidor, vi que estuvieran bien importadas mis clases, la versión de php es soporta en el servidor, no me marca errores de sintaxis en vs code  ¿Cuál podría ser el problema?

Comment: Si lees el trazo de error completo, probablemente te diga en que archivo y en que línea se lanza la excepción. Agrega a la pregunta el código involucrado, la versión de php y laravel, y si tienes instaladas las extensiones de php que requieren laravel y la librería que estás utilizando. También de todo eso que dices que hiciste, muéstranos cómo lo hiciste